# is $Q$ universally measurable? and $R$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces

A separable metric space $(S,d)$ is universally measurable if for every (Borel) probability measure $P$ on the completion $T$ of $S$, there are $A \subset S \subset B$ with $A,B \subset T$ Borel measurable and with $P(A) = P(B)$

I would have thought that both $R$ and $Q$ where to be universally measurable on the Borel sets, but if I try to utilize the definition for $Q$ and take as $P$ the Gaussian measure I will have that $P(A) = 0 \ne P(B)$ since the probability of the rationals is zero and the set $B$ that contains them must have some lenght for which the probability assigned is $>0.$

When I apply the definition to $R$ the closure will also be $R$ and so it becomes impossible to take the two sets $A$ strictly included in $B$.

Have I misunderstood the definition?

EDIT: I am adding a reference for this definition in the hopes to attract an answerer, after the comments I am now convinced that the inclusion is not intended to be strict but I still can't see the usefulness in the definition. The reference is *Real Analysis and Probability*  by R.M. Dudley page 402.

Comment: Note that the rationals form a Borel set in the reals, since in particular they form a countable set. Are you sure the inclusions are supposed to be strict? It seems unnatural. In any case for the rationals you can always add a point which has mass zero to get the strict inclusion.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. So you are saying those inclusions are not strict? it does make a lot more sense as you say probably I have misunderstood notation...

Comment: $S\subset B$ does not mean that $S$ is a proper subset of $B$. We always have $S\subset S$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet so both $R$ and $Q$ are indeed universally measurable?

Comment: @Kore-N this definition seems too easy to satisfy now though...